# Regex/SQL - Find "WHERE" but not between parentheses

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am trying to work out the regex (which I have very little experience with) to check for the presence of one string ("WHERE") within the sql statement, but only if it does not exist between parentheses.

I am using PHP and would appreciate the code or help in that.

I would post code that I have tried, but actually have no idea even where to start.  I've attempted to use other methods to achieve the desired effect, but keep running into one issue or another.

I am trying to build an SQL statement based on a bunch of search criteria, and in each possible search field I need to determine weather to place "WHERE" or "&&" in the sql statement before the where comparison.

I did this by using strstr for awhile, but then had to add a subquery to the "SELECT" portion of the sql which required the use of a "WHERE", so that obviously messed up my method.

Any tips would be excellent.

**EDIT:**

Beginning of statement:

```
SELECT `t1`.*, (SELECT COUNT(`eta`.`time_away`) FROM `table2` WHERE `table2`.`field` = '1') as `time_away`
FROM `table1` `t1`
LEFT JOIN `table3` `t3` ON `t1`.`id` = `t3`.`t3id`
```

Then I have various conditions that will add a WHERE statement, for example:

```
if ($this === true) {
  ### CHECK HERE TO SEE IF WHERE EXISTS, BUT NOT THE WHERE WITHIN THE SUBQUERY
  if ($sql does not contain WHERE outside of subqueries) {
    $sql .= " WHERE ";
  } else {
    $sql .= " && ";
  }
  $sql .= ""; // add my condition here
}
```

This obviously its excessive for only one condition, however my script will have many and in the ones after the first one it will be very necessary.

Comment: Example input/output of valid and invalid cases would be very helpful.

Comment: I find http://regex101.com/ is a good place to test your regexes.

Comment: Edited with more info.

Comment: @LukePittman no need to put your name in your post. It gets automatically inserted below it in that little blue box.

Comment: `"That's the thing about strings," he said. "Who knows where crazy characters like '!@#$%^&*(' may lie?"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove everything that is within () and search WHERE clause in what is left of the sql command:

```
<?php
$string = 'select * from (select * from a where a.id=x) where id=y';
$pattern = '/\(.*\)/';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Will print:

```
select * from where id=y
```

And now you can do your normal 'where search'.

Comment: I like this solution, it is simple, thank you.  How will this work with case?  (WHERE vs where)

Comment: After the replace, you just need an if: `if (stripos($string,'where') !== false) {
    echo 'there is a where clause';
}`. stripos is case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this test:

```
if (preg_match('~(?>(?>[^()w]+|\Bw+|\bw(?!here\b))+|(\((?>[^()]++|(?-1))*\)))*\bwhere\b~i',
               $string, $match)) {
    /* what you have to do */
}
```

The advantage of this solution is that it can deal with nested parenthesis and avoid to miss some content, when other ways will fail, example:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxx (sdfs(df df)g df) WHERE (sdfsdfdsfsdfsdf) xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Pattern details:

```
(?>                    # open the first non capturing group (* atomic)
    (?>                # open the second non capturing group
        [^()w]+        # all characters except ( ) w, one or more times 
      |                # OR
        \Bw+           # some w preceded by a word character (ie: a-zA-Z0-9_)
      |                # OR
        \bw(?!here\b) # some w not preceded by a word character
                       # and not followed by "here"
    )+                 # close the second group and repeat 1 or more times
  |                    # OR
    (                  # open the first capturing group
        \(             # literal (
        (?>            # open the third non capturing group
            [^()]++    # all characters except ( ), one or more times (* possessive)
          |            # OR
            (?-1)      # repeat the last capturing group
        )*             # close the third non capturing group
                       # and repeat it zero or more times
        \)             # literal )
    )                  # close the thirst capturing group
)*                     # close the first non capturing group
                       # and repeat 0 or more times
\bwhere\b              # "where" not followed and not preceded by a word character
```

The goal of this pattern is to match all that is possible until the word "where" outside parenthesis.

Comment: I do appreciate your effort, however I wouldn't use this solution simply for the fact that I have no idea at all what that regex does and would be completely unable to debug it if I had to.

Comment: I will add some explanations.

Comment: I've hit the useful up-arrow for you... thank you for taking the time to do that.